# Python 3.4: mix of class checkbutton and Frame?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm a beginner in object oriented programming.
I have written the following program but I can't get the second windows with the `checkbuttons` and at the same time the result of the mapping of the `checkbutton`.

I have certainly some programming errors but I don't understand where?
I'm in python 3.4

```
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
global listmgw

class Checkbar(object):
    # fenetre d'echange pour selectionner les mgw
    def __init__(self):
        dicorefsys={}
        self.filepath='C:/Desktop/fichiers projet python/travail/'#directory          whitch contains .txt files which will be my reference
        self.filename=''
        self.filepathes=[]
        os.chdir (self.filepath+'/'+self.filename)


        self.reference=''
        print('reference=',self.reference)
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title('Programe Pricipale')
        #self.message = Label(self, text="La reference est:")
        self.mainchoice()
        self.message = Label(self.root, text="choisissez votre reference.").grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky=N,padx =10, pady =5)

        #
        Button(self.root,text='modifier \n Reference', command=self.changeref).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=S,padx =10, pady =5)
        Button(self.root,text='ajout \n supperssion \n MGW', command=allstates()).grid(row=3,column = 3,sticky=S,padx =10, pady =5)
        Button(self.root,text='Quitter', command=self.root.quit).grid(row=3,column = 5,sticky=S,padx =10, pady =5)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def mainchoice(self):
        #
        print ('on dans mainchoice')


    def changeref (self):
        import dicoref
        dicorefsys={}
        #chdir(self.filepath)
        #self.filepath=''
        #self.filename=""
        (self.filepath, self.filename) = os.path.split(askopenfilename())
        print(self.filepath,self.filename)
        dicorefsys=dicoref.reference(self.filepath+'/',self.filename)
        #print(dicorefsys)
        #self.message["text"] = "La MGW de reference est {}.".format(self.filename)
        self.reference=str(dicorefsys['system-name'])
        print('self.reference=',self.reference)
        self.message = Label(self.root, text='La MGW de reference est:  '+str(self.reference)).grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=3,sticky=N,padx =10, pady =5)
        return dicorefsys
        #



class Selecteur(object):
    def __init__(self,parent=None, picks=[]):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      #fen1=Tk
      self.vars = []
      print('on est dans le Selecteur')
      for pick in picks:
        print('pick=',pick)
        var = IntVar()
        self.chk = Checkbutton(fen1, text=pick, variable=var)
        self.chk.grid()
        self.vars.append(var)

    def state(self):
        print('je suis dans state')
        print (("lambda=",lambda var: var.get()))
        print('map=',map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars))
        return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)

    def choixmgwed2(self):

        print('je suis dans choixmgwed2')
        i = 0
        nbvmg = 0
        listmgw = []
        filepath = []
        listmgw = os.listdir('C:/Desktop/fichiers projet python/config_mgw')#directory which contains .txt configuration files
        print('danschoix listgmw=',listmgw)
        nbvmg = len(listmgw)
        filepath.append('C:/Desktop/fichiers projet python/config_mgw/' + listmgw[i])
        i = i + 1
        return listmgw


def allstates(lng):
   print(lng.__doc__)
   print(list(lng.state()))



# Programme principal :
if '__main__' == __name__:
    from tkinter import *
    print('c est parti')
    f = Checkbar()
```

The problems with the actual version is:

1. The checkbutton doesn't appears in a new windows
2. I don't know how to recover the "mapping" of the `checkbutton`.

How can I fix them?

Comment: As far as I can see you never create an instance of `Selecteur`, so there should be no surprise that it never creates a window. You're also calling another class's `__init__` method on it, but it doesn't inherit from that class. Perhaps you want it to?

Comment: This code isn't runnable as-is, there are several problems. Also, the code seems to be much larger than is required to illustrate the problem. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem appears to be that your class inherits from `object`, yet you are trying to call the `__init__` function of the `Frame` class. I *think*  your intention was to inherit from `Frame`:

```
class Selecteur(Frame):
    ...
```

Your code seems to also rely on a global variable named `fen1`, which you never set. It appears that `fen1` refers to a widget, since you use it as the first argument to the creation of the `Checkbutton`. If your class inherits from `Frame`, it seems to make more sense to use `self` rather than `fen1`, so that the checkbutton goes into the frame rather than the root window.

```
self.chk = Checkbutton(self, ...)
```

You have another problem that is unrelated to the `Selecteur` class. You have a button that defines the command attribute like this:

```
Button(..., command=allstates()).grid(...)
```

Since you used `allstates()`, python will immediately call that function, and assign the result to the `command` attribute. However, that function returns a list, not a function.  My guess is that your intention is for the button to call `allstates` when clicked, so you need to change the above to:

```
Button(..., command=allstates).grid(...)
```

Though, `allstates` requires an argument, but I don't know what that argument is supposed to be, so I'm not sure what your real intention is.

Other than that, your code seems to work. The example in your question never actually calls `Selecteur` so that may be another problem, unless that's just a problem with the code posted, and not a problem with your actual code.

Comment: Ok you were right it wes mainly a probleme of windows  (fen=Tk()) declred 2 times, i have used toplevel ans it is solved now i can get my mapping from the main program..  Thanks a lot!!!!